# Put array of data return from Json Result Inside DataTable Using Ajax Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, api, asp.net-mvc-5

please, can you help me with this,
I am trying to get an array of data and object from JSON in datatable using ajax jquery but data table did not read columns of the array

```
$('#Item_Table').DataTable({
        Ajax: {
            url: '/Inv_Items/GetItemByOrgId',
            dataSrc: ""
        },
```

columns:

```
            {
                data: "Item_ID",
                render: function (data, type, Item) {
                    return '<button class="fa fa-edit btn-sm btn btn-success" onclick="EditItem(' + Item.Item_ID + ');" value="Edit" id="Editcategory"></button> &nbsp;' + '<button class="fa fa-edit btn-sm btn btn-success" onclick="DeleteItem(this,' + Item.Item_ID + ');" value="Delete" id="Deletecategory"></button>'
                }
            },
            {data: "English_Name" },
            {data: "Arabic_Name" },
            {data: "Purchase_Price" },
            {data: "Unit_ArabicName" },
            {data: "Unit_EngName" },
            {data: "Itm_Attr_Values[0].CatEngName"},
            {data: "Itm_Attr_Values[0].CatArabName} ]
```

it return me a wrong result in the last two columns of array.

i expected output like this

> [{"Item_ID":54,Arabic_Name":"سير مجموعه","English_Name":"Ser Groups","Purchase_Price":12000","Unit_ArabicName":"قطعة","Unit_EngName":"Piece","Itm_Attr_Values":[{"ID":1054,"Value":"200,215,201","ItemID":54,"AttrID":1017,"AttName":"بيجو","CatArabName":"صيانات سريعة","CatEngName":"Fast Maintenance"},{"ID":1055,"Value":"200,500","ItemID":54,"AttrID":1018,"AttName":"رينو","CatArabName":"صيانات سريعة","CatEngName":"Fast Maintenance"}],
>   ,but the actual output gives me the data of array in columns like this 
>   صيانات سريعه0صيانات سريعه

Answer (score 0):

If the code you posted is exactly the one you're using then you simply missed a closing double quote near `Itm_Attr_Values[0].CatArabName`.

```
$('#Item_Table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '/Inv_Items/GetItemByOrgId',
            dataSrc: ""

        },
 columns: [
            {
                data: "Item_ID",
                render: function (data, type, Item) {
                    return '<button class="fa fa-edit btn-sm btn btn-success" onclick="EditItem(' + Item.Item_ID + ');" value="Edit" id="Editcategory"></button> &nbsp;' + '<button class="fa fa-edit btn-sm btn btn-success" onclick="DeleteItem(this,' + Item.Item_ID + ');" value="Delete" id="Deletecategory"></button>'
                }
            },
            {data: "English_Name" },
            {data: "Arabic_Name" },
            {data: "Purchase_Price" },
            {data: "Unit_ArabicName" },
            {data: "Unit_EngName" },
            {data: "Itm_Attr_Values[0].CatEngName"},
            {data: "Itm_Attr_Values[0].CatArabName"} ] // Missing closing " here
```

Comment: No i didn't miss the closing i just forget to post the end of the code